# are there citations for normalization data to the range [ a, b]?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

Can anyone provide citations for the following formula: 
x=(a-b)((x-min⁡(x))/(max⁡(x)-min⁡(x))+a

I have tried this formula and I got good results

Comment: One reason you can't find a citation might be that the formula is incorrect. I think you mean x=(b-a)((x-min⁡(x))/(max⁡(x)-min⁡(x))+a for some $a < b$.

Comment: You actually have to work when searching our site for answers in order to reduce the hits to less than 1000!  Try https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normalize+linear+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=rescale+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5.

Comment: For citations, see https://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Students-Mary-P-Dolciani/dp/0395430569 (among thousands of possibilities).